# missing graph nodes in tikz

Tags: tikz-trees

i try to run the following code to get graph:

```
  \node {v1}
child { node {v2} 
child { node {v5}
child { node {v10}}
child { node {v11}}}
child { node {v6}
child { node {v12}}}}
child { node {v3}
  child { node {v7}
    child { node {v13} }
    child { node {v8}}}
 child { node {v4}
 child { node {v9}}};
```

but I get 2 missing nodes: v6 and v12, and v2 is connected to v7 as well.
The problem is that v7 is drawn on v6 and v13 on v12. How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please always provide complete small document (MWE: Minimal Working Example) which we can test as it is. BTW, in your code fragment is missed one `}`, so it can't be compiled, if I extend it to an MWE. So solution is to add missed curly brace and change sibling distance at each tree level:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3.141592]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
level/.style={sibling distance=24mm/#1}
                        ]
\node {v1}
    child { node {v2}
        child { node {v5}
            child { node {v10}}
            child { node {v11}}
                }
        child { node {v6}
            child { node {v12}}
                }
            }
    child { node {v3}
        child { node {v7}
            child { node {v13}}
        child { node {v8}}
             }
    child { node {v4}
        child { node {v9}}
            }
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or simpler with `forest` package:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {l sep=6mm, % level separation
            s sep=3mm  % sibling separation
            }
[v1
    [v2 
        [v5
            [v10]
            [v11]
        ]
        [v6
            [v12]
        ]
    ]
    [v3
        [v7
            [v13]
            [v8]
        ]
        [v4 
            [v9]
        ]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]